# Whenever the page gets reloaded, an item in a list gets duplicated in javascript

Tags: javascript

I’m a newbie started js like 2 weeks ago.
I have been making a to-do list.
There are key toDos & finished in localStorage.
I want the value in toDos to go to finished, getting class name “done” if I click the finBtn. Also it should move to the bottom.
At first it works. However, every time the page gets refreshed, the stuff in finished gets duplicated.
This problem’s been bothering me for a week.
Thank you for reading.

```
const toDoForm = document.querySelector(".js-toDoForm"),
    toDoInput = toDoForm.querySelector("input"),
    toDoList = document.querySelector(".js-toDoList");

const TODOS_LS = "toDos";
const FINISHED_LS = "finished";
const NOTSTART_CN = "notStart";
const DONE_CN = "done";


let toDos = [];
let toDosDone = [];


function saveToDos(){
    localStorage.setItem(TODOS_LS, JSON.stringify(toDos));
}

function updateToDos(){
    localStorage.setItem(FINISHED_LS, JSON.stringify(toDosDone));
}

function deleteToDo(event){
    const btn = event.target;
    const li = btn.parentNode;
    toDoList.removeChild(li);
    const cleanToDos = toDos.filter(function(toDo){
        return toDo.id !== parseInt(li.id);
    });
    toDos = cleanToDos;
    saveToDos();
}

function finish(event){
    const btn = event.target;
    const li = btn.parentNode;
    const oldToDos = localStorage.getItem(TODOS_LS);
    const parsedOldToDos = JSON.parse(oldToDos);
    const btnNum = parseInt(li.id) - 1;
    const finishedStuff = parsedOldToDos.splice(btnNum, 1);
    finishedStuff[0].class = DONE_CN;
    li.classList.add(DONE_CN);
    toDos = parsedOldToDos;
    toDosDone = finishedStuff;
    saveToDos();
    updateToDos();
    }

function makeToDos(text){
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    const span = document.createElement("span");
    const delBtn = document.createElement("button");
    const finBtn = document.createElement("button");
    const newId = toDos.length + 1;
    delBtn.innerText="❌";
    delBtn.classList.add("delBtn");
    delBtn.addEventListener("click", deleteToDo);
    finBtn.classList.add("finBtn");
    finBtn.innerText = "✔";
    finBtn.addEventListener("click", finish);
    span.innerText = text;
    li.id = newId;
    li.appendChild(span);
    li.appendChild(delBtn);
    li.appendChild(finBtn);
    toDoList.appendChild(li);
    const toDoObj = {
        text: text,
        id: newId,
        class:""
        };
    toDos.push(toDoObj);
    saveToDos();
}


function handleSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    const currentValue = toDoInput.value;
    makeToDos(currentValue);
    toDoInput.value = "";
}

function loadToDos(){
    const loadedToDos = localStorage.getItem(TODOS_LS);
    const loadedFinToDos = localStorage.getItem(FINISHED_LS);
    if(loadedToDos !== null || loadedFinToDos !== null){
        const parsedToDos = JSON.parse(loadedToDos);
        const parsedFinToDos = JSON.parse(loadedFinToDos);
        parsedToDos.forEach(function(toDo){
            makeToDos(toDo.text);
        });
        parsedFinToDos.forEach(function(done){
            makeToDos(done.text);
        });
    } //else
} //ends of loadToDos

function init(){
    loadToDos();
    toDoForm.addEventListener("submit", handleSubmit);
}

init();
```

Comment: Can you show a run-able example with issue in a JS/HTML Snippet please

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Your localStorage is not cleaning up on page refresh, you should do localStorage.clear(); Each time page load using

Comment: Won't that delete all the items in local storage?

Comment: I tried it, then <Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of null> this arror got occurred. Also everything gone except for TODOS_LS. Other keys disappeared